# Windows 7 Video Driver for ECS Asterope3?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard

I ran Speccy and got the following information about the system:

[image: Motherboard]

[image: Graphics]

I can't seem to find Windows 7 drivers for the VGA (graphics card). Assuming they don't exist., what will be the alternative option in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [Radeon Xpress 200](http://forums.majorgeeks.com/showthread.php?t=191300).  Unfortunately I can't see if there is a driver for it that matches Windows 7 32 bit as [AMD's Driver Page](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx) is down at the moment.  Once it comes back up check that link and fill in the forms to see if you can get a Windows 7 driver.

Edit: The driver selection page is now up: If your card is a Radeon Express 200M (Mobile, laptop) then there is a Windows 7 driver.  If it is a desktop integrated chipset (Express 200) then the driver only goes up to Vista.  However, if you are a desktop try that Vista driver anyway as it may still work just with some features unavailable.

See [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVgBB.png) for the selections to fill out.

Comment: It's still down :( And what if I can't find Windows 7 drivers? What would be options then?

Comment: If AMD doesn't provide a driver then there is not much you can do except run the card in "VESA Modes" which are, as you've no doubt already experienced, dreadfully slow.  If Linux (Xubuntu) is an option for you then you can give the open-source xf86-video-ati driver a try and see if that works out.  I say "Xubuntu" up there and not "Ubuntu" because "Xubuntu" uses a different desktop which is more suited for older hardware than the main version.  Really though the first thing to do is wait for AMD's page to come back up and see what is there.

Comment: @DBC, see my edit.

Comment: It's a desktop. I'll try the Windows Vista driver and see if that helps

Comment: Ok, the selection page is up but the downloads aren't yet.  But now you know what you're looking for.  Ok?

Comment: SOme upstream write/read error :( Why does this have to happen to me? Anyways, I'll try again and let you know. If it works, I'll accept your answer. Damn! Can't even up vote. I hate these rep restrictions

Comment: Ok, right on.  Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screen by running this command in run dialog box.

1. Hit **Win key (start key) + R**, a dialog box will be opened.
2. Type "**dxdiag**" and enter. A screen will appear, please post it here.

I would like to know the PC model and the exact details which displays on the Diagnostic tool.

P.S.: I found this link [here](http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/ati-radeon-xpress-200-1100-rc410-rc415-graphics-driver-download,22805.html).

Comment: Damn! Can't update answer with another link as the 10 rep limit isn't allowing me to post more than 2 links. Anyways, here is the dxdiag screenshot http://i39.tinypic.com/t4uzpv.png

Comment: Well unfortunately your system model doesn't line up Windows 7. I found this [link](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&lc=en&os=228&product=3349175&query=SR1933IL&tool=&#N184) & I assume this your system model. BTW, is it an external VGA or an internal one?

Comment: Access denied page is coming up when I try to download the Windows Vista driver :(

Comment: well for me it gives only a firmware update link to download. Sorry, no luck :/

I assume your pc supports upto XP. You still did not say whether its an internal one or an external one. On the same "dxdiag" menu, check the display tab whether its displays the driver details there by any chance :S

Comment: The display tab doesn't give much info. It's an integrated chipset for sure as there is no video card attached.

Comment: @Azker, what do you mean by "external VGA or internal one"?  That doesn't make sense.  Graphics cards are on the mainboard as a chipset or as a card inside the machine.  Neither is "external."  Some USB attached cards can generate video signals but this machine is way too old for that.  Also, the link you gave to HP's site does not match his model of computer.  Bad advice.

Comment: After all search I did, I still did not come across a win 7 driver. I assume it supports up to vista.

Comment: @Bill according the PC model, it redirects to HP site. Even in search it shows anonymous links to HP site. and that is the model which tally with the "dxdiag".

Comment: Damn it, you're right.  But still does not list Windows 7 32 bit drivers.

Comment: What would a firmware update do?

Comment: Nvm..it gave the description of what it does on that page itself :)